# automatically calculate total value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to calculate sum of the numbers the user has entered automatically.When the user delete one number the sum should auto calculate.How to calculate sum of array values using jquery.Please help me to solve this problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-control').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.form-control').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
            {
                totalvalue += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#totalvalue').html(totalvalue);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center;">INVOICE</h2>        

        <form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='index.php'>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
                            <th>S. No</th>
                            <th>Job ID</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
                            <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='txt_jobid' name='txt_jobid[]'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='txt_quantity' name='txt_quantity[]'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='txt_price' name='txt_price[]'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='txt_totalprice' name='txt_totalprice[]'/> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ Add More</button>
                </div>
            </form>     Total: <div id="totalvalue">0</div>
```

SUBMIT FORM

```
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't see any php code?

Comment: Remove the `(jQuery)` at the end, it's wrong there. It's not an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime you used `total` and sometimes `totalValue`. Name the variables the same. And remove the `(jQuery)` at the end. It's wrong there.

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-control').change(function() {
        var total = 0;

        $('.form-control').each(function() {
            if( $(this).val() != '' )
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        $('#totalvalue').html(total);
    });

    // trigger initial calculation if wanted
    .change();
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/
Initial calculation: https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/1/

Full working example of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/8/

Comment: sorry dat was my mistake.plz ignore it

Comment: But its working. So what's your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/

Comment: i'm getting first input values.others are not calculating

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this now?!

Comment: the inputs are created by jquery auto filled.I need to calculate that input values.

Comment: @eisbehr You need to add `keyup` event to code. See https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/2/

Comment: thanks for trying. i can calculate anuy input values dynamically

Comment: @mohammad Why? Was this wished by the creator? It's not wrong, but I don't understand how this helps here ...

Comment: http://demo.smarttutorials.net/jquery-autocomplete-mutiple-fields-ajax-php-mysql/  I need to calculate total price value dynamically

Comment: @eisber,@Mohammad, plz check it and help me to solve this issue

Comment: Like this again? It's a bit dirty, but it works. :) https://jsfiddle.net/0zpkow5L/4/

Comment: @eisbehr thanks,calculation is working but when i delete one field amount not decreased.Cany you fix it.

Comment: Great. I've added the example to the my answer. Please mark it as success then.

Comment: @eisbehr sometimes serial number comes in "N"?why this error occured?check it your jsfiddle

Comment: I've created a demo there for you. It is not a fully woking script, it an example. Therefore there is no number display for new rows. Create a counter for that number then. See my `addRow` function. You should really start to do something on your own and not just letting me do the work for you. Your inital question is more than answered, I'm out.

Comment: When I am trying to get the result inside input field <input name="text" id="totalvalue"> it does not work however it works with <span id="totalvalue"></span> any suggestion please

Comment: Sorry I was doing something wrong, its working